# Why i cant change nav-link color on CSS?

Tags: html, css, boost-random

1) Why I can not change the nav-link color on CSS?

I'm trying to change the color of MENUTEST's (nav-link) to white, but it's not working

and

2) Add a line white above every MENUTEST's texts (just like [u] but above) How to do it?

What do i'm doing wrong?

navbar.php

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top" style="background-color: #083F2C;">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" height="60" width="160"></a>

<!-- Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">
<ul class="navbar-nav">

<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="index.php">MENUTEST</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="Preview" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MENUTEST
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="Preview" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MENUTEST
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="Preview" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MENUTEST
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ana Tereza fala em São Paulo sobre o Direito de Regresso no Fomento Comercial</a> -->
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>

</div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="Preview" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MENUTEST
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>

</div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="Preview" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MENUTEST
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SUBMENUTEST</a>

</div>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">MENUTEST</a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

And navbar.css

```
/* MENUTEST */
.nav-link a {
  font-color: white;
}

/* SUBMENUTEST */
.dropdown-menu {
  background: #EDEFF1;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #78828D;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

...............................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and take a little further than just the class and  try -> li, a, .nav-link and then whatever css you want.

I can see you are using Bootstrap so it might be inheriting something. A trick I always use it to go to the Chrome browser and right click on the thing I want to change and click on "inspect" this will make it possible to see what css lies behind the item you want to change and you can then try to edit it in the browser and if it works copy that code and insert into your own css file.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! Your advice work

What i changed was:
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {

Comment: Did u know how to do a line above the fonts? like <u>Text</u>
But above...

Comment: use "text-decoration: overline";

Comment: Lol! You saved me a lot! Thank you so much!
One last thing is it possible to change this line spacing to the text and get a bigger line? I mean, more higher?

Comment: Not sure I understand.. There is something called line-height, maybe play with that? :)

Comment: Dont work ;\
Yep, i wanna change the line-height and the distance between text and line :S

Comment: Dont know why line height isn't working. Have you searched on google?

Answer (score 2):

`font-color` is not a css property. You'll want to use `color`.

```
.nav-link a {
  // font-color: white;
  color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<div class="menuBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="two.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        ....
   </ul>
</div>

// specific CSS for your menu
div.menuBar li.selected a { color: #FF0000; } 
// more general CSS
li.selected a { color: #FF0000; }`
```

How about this, have you tried using `li.selcted a{color:#FF0000;}`.

Comment: .nav-link a {
  color:#1e1e1e;
}

Not change too :(

Comment: try this new answer that i posted